# Where should the rules file be located in TokenRegex(StanfordCoreNLP) in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, stanford-nlp

So I was doing an example on TokenRegex pattern matching using stanford core nlp library. Need help in placing the rules file in appropriate location. Tried placing it in src folder but it didn't work

Code:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException 
{
    // set properties
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,tokensregex");
    props.setProperty("tokensregex.rules", "basic_ner.rules");
    props.setProperty("tokensregex.matchedExpressionsAnnotationKey","edu.stanford.nlp.examples.TokensRegexAnnotatorDemo$MyMatchedExpressionAnnotation");

    // build pipeline
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

    // annotate
    Annotation ann = new Annotation("There will be a big announcement by Apple Inc today at 5:00pm.  " +
        "She has worked at Miller Corp. for 5 years.");
    pipeline.annotate(ann);


    // show results
    System.out.println("---");
    System.out.println("tokens\n");
    for (CoreMap sentence : ann.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) 
    {
        for (CoreLabel token : sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class)) 
        {
            System.out.println(token.word() + "\t" + token.ner());
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    System.out.println("---");
    System.out.println("matched expressions\n");
    for (CoreMap me : ann.get(MyMatchedExpressionAnnotation.class)) 
    {
        System.out.println(me);
    }
}
```

}

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYwJu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work if you put the file `basic_ner.rules` in the working directory (which is not going to be "src").  You should find the default working directory in Eclipse.  I'm assuming it would just be the root directory of the whole project.  You could also just put the absolute path of the rules file.